# How can I create this (table) with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to create this design With CSS. The red text/area (responsive) should be responsive/flexible on smaller screens.

The design I want to create with CSS:
[image]

I can do it simple with a html-table but tables should not be used in design.

I have looked into unordered list and hide the bullets and replace by images but have problems with the spece between content and the responsive area.

Here is some code but I cant get it working when I add text to the right of the facebook and twitter button.

```
<div id="fact-footer">
<img id="img-fb" src="img/fb.svg" alt="Facebook">
<img id="img-fb" src="img/tw.svg" alt="Facebook">
<a id="more-facts" href="#">NÄSTA ></a>
</div>


#fact-footer {
bottom: 0;
font-size: 12px;
}

#img-fb, #img-twitter {
float: left;    
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
}

#img-fb {
margin-right: 10px;
}

#more-facts {
float: right;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 8px;
border: none;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #26a69a;
color: white;
}
```

The code aboe results in this

[image]

Comment: are you using bootstrap framework? if yes this can be easily achieved using the grids in bootstrap..

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: I'am not using any framwork

Comment: @caramba I have added some code that works fine without the text beside facebook and twitter. I get a mess when I add the text.

Comment: https://noti.st/rachelandrew/QEhSSc

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids

Comment: Yep, now I see. You will need to wrap. And if the text next to facebook is not in the image you will need to write it inside the wrap. (I hope the text is not the image) then with quentins links above you should be able to make it. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u expecting like this:

```css
body{
  margin:10px;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;    
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
span{
  color:black;
}
.flex-item:nth-of-type(5) { flex-grow: 1; }

.flex-item {  
  background: #e0e0e0;
  color: white;
  padding:6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn{
   background-color: #5fda64; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ecdc7512a9.js"></script>

<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">
      <i style="color:blue"  class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i>     
  </li>
    <li class="flex-item" >
      <span > facebook <br/> Account  </span>    
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item"><i style="color:lightblue" class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i> </li>    
  <li class="flex-item"> <span>Twitter <br/> Account </span>  </li>
  <li class="flex-item">(responsive)</li>
  <li class="flex-item">
    <button class="btn">NASTA ></button>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flex you may use this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"> facebook image here </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"> twiter image here </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"> text </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"> nasta image here </div>
</div>

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col-sm-3 {
  width: 25%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Give the `.col-sm-3` a border and see what happens (and you are using Bootstap without using the full package).